# Page item type shuttle box with search function

Tags: oracle, search, filter, oracle-apex, interactive

I'm trying to create in Apex a Page item of type Shuttle with a Filter in order to search the select list on the left side.

The problem is just after changing the search parameter and after the select list was refreshed all the already selected items will disappear from the right side of the box because these items could not match the new select list on the left side.

It is expected that the already selected items stay selected on the right side and could not be overwritten by the new selected ones.
Has anyone faced this kind of problem in Apex and had a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem. Create text fiel for search. In shuttle in where class set connection with yest search.Then in default value set plsql expression with this shuttle value.